# Can a HTTP PUT request specify additional information as well as the file data?

Tags: php, c++, http, winapi, wininet

I wish to send some small files (crash log files) from my application to a web server. libCurl or WinINet seem the most obvious options, to send a simple HTTP PUT request. However is it possible to inform the server any more information about the file, like the file-name or user name, or does a PUT request by definition simply send the file contents and nothing else?

POST allows much more information but also seems far more complex, having to send content types and fake form submission, etc... if POST is the only option to do what I want what would minimal code to send a file look like, and what would my server code look like to receive it?

Comment: You could use HTTP headers.

Comment: If you control the server you can send anything you want. If not you need to find out what the server accepts.

Comment: @Thilo you can add headers to PUT? I'm a application developer so while I've done some web coding, HTTP is unknown to me - no answer is too simple :)

Comment: Basically comes down to what @AlanStokes said: if you control the server, transmit it in a form that is most convenient for you (which I guess is a POST). If not, you have to ask them how to transmit the data.